# Lots of warning messages in hive cli after removing jndiLookup Class

Tags: hive, log4j, jndi, hivecli

After removing JndiLookupClass from the classpath under $HIVE_HOME/lib/log4j-core-2.6.2.jar we are getting multiple warnings when we open hive cli and also while running the queries.

PFA error lines.
2021-12-17 18:47:32,880 main WARN JNDI lookup class is not available because this JRE does not support JNDI. JNDI string lookups will not be available, continuing configuration. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup

We have tried commenting the line #appenders = console, DRFA in log4j2.properties file present under $HIVE_HOME/conf but still the issue is persisting.
There are no updates in the official documentation of hive.

Can someone help with the fix.
**Is there any way to suppress the warning messages as it is hampering the output.**